# Svelte alias/rename props

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

Is there any way to rename/alias props in svelte?

For example, if I have a component which takes a `foo` prop but I also want a `foo` local variable for the current state, is there any way to rename the incoming prop a bit like this:

```
export let foo as forceFoo;
let foo = forceFoo | null;
```

Normally the correct answer is one of these two:

1. Rename the prop to something like `initialFoo`
2. Rename the state

Renaming the prop is not appropriate in this case - it's the public API of the component and it's not an initial state, it's an optional override that forces the value of that field.

Renaming the state is ok for a single field and usually works well for generic components, but becomes horrible and unwieldy when the component is a form with many fields and has to pass those fields on to a save function that expects them to have the right names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper syntax is the following:

```html
<script>
  // aliased prop
  let forceFoo
  export { forceFoo as foo }

  // local state
  let foo = forceFoo
</script>
```